# Run length decoding in OCaml

Tags: syntax, ocaml

In my function below, lp is of form as in example [0,a;3,r;7,p;2,a].

The function run_length_decode takes lp and returns in above example [r;r;r;p;p;p;p;p;p;p;a;a].

```
let rec run_length_decode lp = match (List.hd lp) with [] ->[]
| [0] -> rle_decode (List.tl (List.tl lp))
| _ -> (List.hd [List.tl]):: run_length_decode (List.hd  (List.hd lp) -1)::(List.hd [List.tl])::(List.tl [List.tl])
```

It says there is some error in (List.hd  (List.hd lp) -1) where I want to take the head and decrement and (List.hd [List.tl])::(List.tl [List.tl]) where I want to concatenate tail of the list to decremented head and recurse.

The idea is to check three cases - (1) if lp is empty then return empty terminate, (2) if head of lp is 0 then skip to next section of lp and (3) if head of lp is bigger than 0 then print the letter to be displayed and recursively call RUNLENGTHDECODE with modified lp where the head of lp is decremented and concatenated with tail of lp. The above code is not working. What is the issue? How to fix?

Comment: You say the code isn't working. What exactly is the problem? Note that local names must start with a lower case letter in OCaml. You can't actually have a function named `RUNLENGTHDECODE`. You can name it `rUNLENGTHDECODE` if you insist on lots of caps. Personally I would name it something like `run_length_decode`.

Comment: You may want to have a look to https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html#Decodearunlengthencodedlistmedium

Answer (score 1):

It can help you :

```
let run_length_decode lp =
  let rec aux (n,c) acc =    
    if n<=0 then acc else aux (n-1,c) (c::acc) 
  in
  List.fold_right aux lp []
;;
```

Test :

```
# run_length_decode [0,'a';3,'r';7,'p';2,'a'];;
- : char list = ['r'; 'r'; 'r'; 'p'; 'p'; 'p'; 'p'; 'p'; 'p'; 'p'; 'a'; 'a']
```

Explanations :

- acc is an accumulator
- aux is an auxiliary function

Comment: What does aux and acc mean?

Comment: @ML. acc is an accumulator an aux an auxiliary function.

Comment: @V.Michel how is input to inner fuction is passed?

Comment: @ML. via fold_left.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to use `List.hd` and `List.tl` to decompose tuples like `(3,r)` which form the elements of your input list. The problem is that tuples aren't lists. As the tuples are pairs, you can use `fst` and `snd` to do the decomposition.

Personally I would recommend pattern matching instead, like this:

```
match lp with
| [] -> ...
| (repetitions,character) :: rest -> ...
```

There seem to be some more problems with your code:

- You imply that `lp` is of type `(int * char) list` but have a pattern matching case of type `int list`.
- `List.hd [whatever]` is just the same as `whatever`, as square brackets are a list constructor.
- `[List.tl]` (without any argument given to `List.tl`) is a valid value (of type `` (`a list -> `a list) list ``), but probably not what you want.

Comment: Just to clarify, the input list ```[0,a;3,r;7,p;2,a]``` is actually a list of tuples ```[ (0,a); (3,r); (7,p); (2,a) ]``` -- notice the difference between ```,``` and ````;````.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't see why an accumulator or auxiliary function would be necessary - even though it probably is more efficient, because it is tail-recursive - and the other answer does not give an explicit version of the function that works. Therefore:)

If I try to stay as close as possible to the flawed code from the question, I get:

```
let rec run_length_decode lp = match lp with [] ->[]
| (0,_)::_ -> run_length_decode (List.tl lp)
| _ -> (snd (List.hd lp)):: run_length_decode (((fst  (List.hd lp) -1),(snd (List.hd lp)))::(List.tl lp))
```

But I would probably write this myself as:

```
let rec run_length_decode lp =
  match lp with
  | [] -> []
  | (0,_)::lp' -> run_length_decode lp'
  | (n,c)::lp' -> c::run_length_decode ((n-1,c)::lp')
```

In both cases:

```
# run_length_decode [0,'a';3,'r';7,'p';2,'a'];;
- : char list = ['r'; 'r'; 'r'; 'p'; 'p'; 'p'; 'p'; 'p'; 'p'; 'p'; 'a'; 'a']
```